# Overcome the replacement has length zero Error

Tags: r

I am running a for loop on dataset to retrieve locations near a certain longitude and latitude values and the for loop stops whenever there is NA.  Is there a possible why to continue executing the for loop and ignore the missing information.

for( i in 1:nrow(top)){

```
 x <- (top[i,c("V3")]) ////latitude value
 y <- (top[i,c("V4")]) /// longitude value

res <- GNfindNearby(lat=x, lng=y,radius=0.01) /// near by places
top[i,"Location"] <- res
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. What is `GNfindNearby`?
2. Try using `spDists` and `spDistsN1` functions from **sp** package.

Comment: GNfindNearby is a function in the geonames package that retrieves nearest places  near a certain longitude and latitude